# How to replace numeric values of a column of a SQL table view with text aliases?

Tags: sql, qt, view, alias

I am using Qt5.
I managed to connect to a sql database and using `QtCreator` I have now a `QTableView` that is nicely populated using `SELECT * ...` from a test table I previously defined with MS SQL Manager...

Only one thing I would like to change:
...One column named "Error" has now numeric/integer values like: -101, -102, -105, and so on. To be honest I would prefer to have "Error opening file" instead of -101, also "Socket error" instead of -105, etc. you get the point.
Also, this "modification" must not affect the table in the database, but only the table-view.

Please, do you have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a subclass of `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplement its `data` virtual method. It can be something like this:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
  QVariant result = QSortFilterProxyModel::data(index, role);
  if (index.column() == ERROR_COLUMN) {
    result = error_to_string(result.toInt());
  }
  return result;    
}
```

See [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) to learn how to use proxy models.

Comment: Thanks Pavel!  Very good idea!   I will "chew" it tomorrow, as now it's quite late here and I'm a lil'bit tired :)   THANKS :)

Comment: Since it's a 1:1 mapping, a better idea would be to use an `QIdentityProxyModel` in this case.

Comment: I think I understand, yet can you elaborate a little bit, please?

Comment: Good idea. Just use `QIdentityProxyModel` instead of `QSortFilterProxyModel` as base class and implement `data` as I described above.